# How to subtract an interval from a datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, subtraction

How to calculate `start_time` given `finish_time` and `différent_time`?

Ex:(2021-10-12 23:50:00 - 30s = 2021-10-12 23:20:00

`différent_time` is the quantity of seconds.

Comment: dateadd() would be the way to go.   dateadd(second,-30,finish_time)

Comment: Just an aside... your sample data is subtracting 30 minutes not 30 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtract the different_time from the finish_time. Here's an example using variables (hence, the @ sign) instead of field values, but it should get you on your way.

```
declare @finish_time as datetime = '12:00:00'
declare @start_time as datetime
declare @different_time as datetime = '0:00:30'

set @start_time = @finish_time - @different_time

select @start_time
```

This will return a time that is 30 seconds earlier than your finish time. In this case: 11:59:30 AM.

In a query, it would look something like this:

```
select [finish_time] - [different_time] as [start_time]
```